# The template does not see the resources folder

Tags: java, html, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

I recently needed to move all my resources from a folder
**3DShop/src/main/webapp/resources/**
to
**3DShop/src/main/resources/**
After the transfer, css styles on the pages stopped working and images also stopped displaying.

I changed the paths in the spring settings in the addResourceHandlers method, and the path in my html template when I included the link.
However, the styles and pictures still don't work. I think I'm not specifying the addresses correctly in the addResourceHandlers method. How to prescribe the correct path, please explain.

**My spring config class:**

```
package ru.shop.three_d_print.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.*;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.shop.three_d_print")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/WEB-INF/classes/static/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/classes/static/");
    }

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver()
    {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/classes/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine()
    {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry)
    {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() { return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource()); }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/three_d_shop_db");
        dataSource.setUsername("*******");
        dataSource.setPassword("*******");

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

**Main page using css styles:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>3d_shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0">
    <div class="page">
        <header th:insert="~{other/fragments :: header}"></header>

        <main style="margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%;">
            <h2> Welcome! </h2>
            <button>Text</button>
            <div>
                <p>
                    ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diem
                    nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lacreet dolore magna aliguam erat volutpat.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diem
                    nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lacreet dolore magna aliguam erat volutpat.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diem
                    nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lacreet dolore magna aliguam erat volutpat.
                </p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="center_frame"></div>
        </main>

        <footer th:insert="~{other/fragments :: footer}" style="margin-top: auto;" ></footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Project hierarchy:**

[image]

Comment: Replace `/WEB-INF/classes` with `classpath:` for the resource location and remove that `/WEB-INF/classes` from the resource path. So you should end up with `registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");`

Comment: @ M. Deinum
Thanks a lot, it really worked.

Answer (score 1):

The `/WEB-INF/classes/` folder is basically the root of the class path, so instead you should use the `classpath:` prefix.

For the path section it is for matching incoming requests to see where to retrieve the resources from. I doubt that that has `/WEB-INF/classes/` in the URL, so remove it from that part.

```java
registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
```

This is what you should end up with for a proper mapping.